# How to add a new row after every unique entries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have to add a new row at the end of each person information. In the new row which we will add all the information will be same as last row like `name`, `last_update`, and new `date` will have same value as last row. But visited column should always have value `abc` and start date will have same value as `last_update` and date will have same value as new date.

lets say dataframe looks like this:

| Name | last_update | New date | visited | start_date | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ravi | 22-04-2010 | 22-04-2010 | abc | 22-09-1987 | 24-04-2010 |
| Ravi | 27-04-2010 | 28-04-2010 | xyz | 24-07-2001 | 2-08-2015 |
| Rajesh | 22-06-2012 | 22-07-2012 | yyy | 12-08-2005 | 25-08-2012 |
| Rajesh | 24-02-2014 | 25-04-2014 | zzz | 18-06-2002 | 26-06-2014 |

New dataframe will be

| Name | last_update | New date | visited | start_date | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ravi | 22-04-2010 | 22-04-2010 | abc | 22-09-1987 | 24-04-2010 |
| Ravi | 27-04-2010 | 28-04-2010 | xyz | 24-07-2001 | 2-08-2015 |
| Ravi | 27-042010 | 28-04-2010 | abc | 27-042010 | 28-04-2010-----newly added row |
| Rajesh | 22-06-2012 | 22-07-2012 | yyy | 12-08-2005 | 25-08-2012 |
| Rajesh | 24-02-2014 | 25-04-2014 | zzz | 18-06-2002 | 26-06-2014 |
| Rajesh | 24-02-2014 | 25-04-2014 | abc | 24-02-2014 | 25-04-2014----newly added row |

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add one more column with id like conversation_id or sender_id either of it you can choose, and make sure to use it as the primary key.
So, now whenever you save the information it will be like the following:

```
id               |Name   |last_update    |New date   |visited |start_date    |date
gdast767jd       |Ravi   |22-04-2010     |22-04-2010 |abc     |22-09-1987    |24-04-2010
jagsdjgs01       |Ravi   |27-04-2010     |28-04-2010 |xyz     |24-07-2001    |2-08-2015
agsdjgs02        |Ravi   |27-042010      |28-04-2010 |abc     |27-042010     |28-04-2010-----newly added row
jagsdjyuay       |Rajesh |22-06-2012     |22-07-2012 |yyy     |12-08-2005    |25-08-2012
jag09sad         |Rajesh |24-02-2014     |25-04-2014 |zzz     |18-06-2002    |26-06-2014
ja17987h         |Rajesh |24-02-2014     |25-04-2014 |abc     |24-02-2014    |25-04-2014----newly added row
```

Above ids are imaginary.